# Ajax Methods Not Working with Angular Routing

Tags: asp.net, ajax, angular, model-view-controller

Here is my router config file;

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'giris', pathMatch: 'full' },

  //Route for Ajax methods
  { path: 'Ajax/*', redirectTo: 'Ajax/*', pathMatch: 'full' },

  { path: 'giris', component: GirisComponent },
  { path: 'biyografi', component: BiyografiComponent },
  { path: 'galeri', component: GaleriComponent },
  { path: 'siirleri', component: SiirleriComponent },

  { path: '**', component: GirisComponent }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

And here is my service codes;

```
@Injectable()
export class CPService {
  private menuLink: string = "Ajax/Menu";

  constructor(private _http: Http) {}

  getMenu() {
    return this._http.get(this.menuLink)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .catch(this._errorHandler);
  }

  _errorHandler(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error || "Server Error");
  }
}
```

And here is my Web Method;

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Menu() {
  var categories = entity.Category.Where(a => a.Active == true && a.Display == true).ToList();

  foreach (var item in categories) {
    item.RouteUrl = item.RouteUrl.ToLower().Replace("-", "");
  }

  return Json(categories, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

When i try to access the Web Method it just open a normal web page :( It doesn't call Menu method from AjaxController when i debug.

I'm waiting for your answers. I'm new at Angular :)

Answer (score 0):

I just added the code below to the beginning of my RouteConfig.cs file

```
  routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Ajax",
       url: "Ajax/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Ajax", action = "Menu", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
```

Then i changed my angular router config file like below (I just removed route for Ajax methods);

```
   const appRoutes: Routes = [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'giris', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'giris', component: GirisComponent },
      { path: 'biyografi', component: BiyografiComponent },
      { path: 'galeri', component: GaleriComponent },
      { path: 'siirleri', component: SiirleriComponent },
      { path: '**', component: GirisComponent }
   ];

   export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```